# Confusion free resolution

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I am studying the following free resolution. $R=K[x,y]$ with $K$ a field.

$$0\longrightarrow R\stackrel{\begin{pmatrix} y\\-x \end{pmatrix}}\longrightarrow R^2 \stackrel{\begin{pmatrix} x & y \end{pmatrix}}\longrightarrow R\longrightarrow R/(x,y)$$

I don't understand the first map. We construct a map $K[x,y]\to K[x,y]\oplus K[x,y]$ by sending $1\to (y,-x)$. But when we construct a map from a polynomial ring, don't we need to specify the image of $1$, $x$ and $y$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sequence of linear maps is very general and has nothing to do with indeterminates: it also makes sense in any ring $R$, for arbitrary elements $x,y\in R$. It simply *happens* that $R$ is here a polynomial ring in two indeterminates.

So, explicitly the linear map is here
\begin{align}
K[x,y]&\longrightarrow K[x,y]\times K[x,y], \\
F(x,y)&\longmapsto\bigl(yF(x,y),-xF(x,y)\bigr).
\end{align}

Comment: I understand! And now how do we prove that this is indeed an exact sequence?

Comment: It corresponds to the fact that $(x,y)$ is a regular sequence in the ring (it is even the definition of a regular sequence via the *Koszul complex*).SFo you have  to do some arithmetic of  polynomials  to show that $x$ is a non-zero divisor in $R$, and $y$ is a non-zero divisor modulo $(x)$, which  shouldn't be hard…

Answer (score 0):

We need to specify the image of $1,x,y$ when we consider a map from a polynomial ring as a ring. Here it is a module homomorphism and as module it is generated by $1$.